# NameError: uninitialized constant String::Stemmer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, porter-stemmer

I'm using the stemmer gem for ruby to stem some words. I have a class naivebayes.rb more or less like the following:

```
require "stemmer"
.....

class Naivebayes
    include Stemmable

    def clean_word(word)
       ..
       ...
       stem(word)

    end

end
```

I have omitted some of the code. The same code runs perfectly fine when I run it outside of my rails app like so: ruby naivebayes.rb. However, when I run it in rails console or within my rails app in a controller I received the following error:

```
**NameError: uninitialized constant String::Stemmer**
```

This is puzzling me beyond anything! Haven't found other problem similar to this so I'm asking if anyone has any idea how to go about resolving this or what am I missing.

Thanks!

Comment: did you add: `gem 'stemmer'` to your `Gemfile`???

Comment: yes I have it in my Gemfile! It is loaded as stemmer 1.0.1

Comment: that library was created in 2005, you probably should be using something newer

Comment: the library works fine! As I mentioned, it works fine when I run it from the terminal with: ruby name_of_file.rb  but not inside the rails app or rails console! I get that error above!I also tried fast-stemmer gem but I get the same error!

Comment: okey looks like fast-stemmer was conflicting with stemmer now that I added it. So I removed stemmer and it's working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

fast-stemmer (https://github.com/romanbsd/fast-stemmer) works fine. Add `gem 'fast-stemmer'` to your Gemfile. Remove `gem 'stemmer'` from Gemfile if you have it as it conflicts with fast-stemmer.